# does (SQL) JOINING on TABLES ALWAYS create Cartesian products of those tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

does JOINING on TABLES ALWAYS create Cartesian products of those tables ?
if a problem can be solved by sub-query and Joining which should i prefer ?
which one is fast and memory saving ?

*All the questions are tightly coupled, so please dont tell to open another thread* :(

**MySQL 5**

Comment: It's a google question, and a lot of duplicate are already on stackoverflow... http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=join+sql+how+it+works

Comment: nope it's not a duplicate :) there are some sub-questions too !

Comment: @Scorpi0: [You missed the memo.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)

Comment: For questions about "which one will be fast", about the only way to definitively answer the question is to run both queries against your actual database, with all (or a representative sample of) your data. Since you're the only one in the position of being able to do that, we won't be able to answer the last question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603373/sql-query-returns-fake-duplicate-results/5603387#5603387   IN THIS CASE WHAT YOU WILL RECOMMENDED distinct OR JOIN ? if not **DISTINCT** why ? i use DISTINCT a lot ! is it really a bad thing ?

Comment: @Bobby, well, I know, but this is not a reply, just a comment...

Comment: @scorpi0: It's still not useful nor helpful nor welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does JOINING on TABLES ALWAYS create Cartesian products of those tables ?

Yes, but normall that is then filtered down and the query optimizer is smart enough to take a more efficient approach. Anyhow, all joins without conditions ARE cartesian products ni the start.

> if a problem can be solved by sub-query and Joining which should i prefer ?

Depends a lot on the query optimizer and the data in question. As in: Try it out. Prettym uch the only way.

> which one is fast and memory saving ?

Again - try it out.

This stuff really depends no the table sizes involved AND THE FILTER CONDITIONS. Basically a materialized cartesian product in most cases is bad programming (ups, forgot the fitler conditions) or a very bad query plan. In most cases the cartesian product iwll never materialize and the query optimizer will use a different approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603373/sql-query-returns-fake-duplicate-results/5603387#5603387   IN THIS CASE WHAT YOU WILL RECOMMENDED distinct OR JOIN ? if not distinct why ? i use DISTINCT a lot ! is it really a bad thing ?

Comment: DIstinct is the worst thing you can do. I would suggest a book about sql ;) Beginner level. Practically try things out. Professionals often do on non trivial databases. Experienceh elps, but a lot depends on teh data in question.

Comment: but what is wrong with distinct ? it solves lots of problem ! :)

Comment: The fact that in order to guarantee distinct the server hat to collect all the data and remove all possible duplicates. This is normally the msot expensive operation you can ever have. Possibly ltos of temp space usage. As I said - get a decent book on sql.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, joining always creates a Cartesian product. That's why you usually add a condition to be met:
   `JOIN a, b ON key_a = key_b`. If the key_b is a UNIQUE KEY in table b, you will have at most one row from b for each row of a.
2. In most cases, joins are faster, but there are exceptions (`WHERE x IN ANY (subquery)`)
3. See 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, JOINING on tables always create Cartesian products of those tables. 
you can't prefer join or sub-query because it depends on your data size 
so, you have to try the two ways then you can decide which one is more appropriate 
to your query